# 404-error when using & in url

Tags: php, yii2

I'm building a website with yii2 and xampp and there I have a NavBar with

```
 $menuItems = [...
                ['label' => 'Mitlesen', 'url' => ['/site/uebersicht&seite=1']],
               ...]
```

This leads to the site: `index.php?r=site%2Fuebersicht%26seite%3D1`

And here I'm getting the error-message:

```
Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request: site/uebersicht&seite=1
```

When I delete the `&seite=1` the error disappears.
And when I call `... site/uebersicht&seite=1` directly in the browser, it works fine, too.

Comment: I guess Rupert is right. Try to call `index.php?r=site/uebersicht%26seite%3D1` if this don't work and `index.php?r=site/uebersicht&seite=1` rupter found the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use `'url' => ['/site/uebersicht', 'seite' => 1]`

Comment: guess this should be `'url' => ['r' => '/site/uebersicht', 'seite' => 1]`

Comment: but in his url he has `?r=`

Comment: No. The first parameter should be without 'r'. This array is then processed by Url::to() (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail).

Comment: Yes, it worked with the 'url' => ['/site/uebersicht', 'seite' => 1]

Answer (score 0):

You are url encoding the url so the & gets converted to %26.

You need to make sure no url encoding occurs on this url.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for a reference to url encoded characters.

However, I'm not sure why you would want to put an "&" in the query string if there is no "?" first. Perhaps you want to swap it over?

A proper query string may look like this:

htttp://site.com/some/route/?name=sam&country=spain

Answer (score 0):

It is an incorrect query string. You should put `?` instead of `&`. So your url should be `/site/uebersicht?seite=1`